# How to get argv[k] into another string?

Tags: c, string, pointers, argv

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

   char Q[MAXCHAR];
   Q=argv[k+1];}
```

Q is an array while argv[k+1] is a pointer.
How can I get the content of argv[k+1] into Q?

Comment: pointer and array are the same thing, actually. You just need `strcpy`.

Comment: @Sulthan Pointers and arrays are not the same. Arrays decay to pointers in certain circumstances; that's all.

Comment: @underscore_d Isn't an array in C just a chunk of continuous memory identified by the pointer to the beginning?

Comment: @Sulthan An array is a distinct class of object, which is often _converted to a pointer_, but is not a pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4608421/2757035 The name of the array retains important information, chiefly the array's `sizeof`, which a pointer is incapable of conveying. Hence the need to pass array sizes everywhere, of course.

Comment: @Sulthan contiguous chunk of memory yes, pointer no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to copy C-strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings)

Comment: @Sulthan: Please (a) read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com), and (b) delete your initial comment. The false idea that arrays are "really" pointers is one of the most common misconceptions about C. Please don't spread it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

```
snprintf(Q, MAXCHAR, "%s", argv[k]);
```

(edited : first version recommended strncpy).

Comment: `strncpy` is never what you want. If you want a truncating copy (itself a dubious method), use `snprintf`.

Comment: @melpomene : Why would `strncpy`not be recommended in this case ?

Comment: Because `strncpy` should never be used. It does weird things and it's misnamed (it doesn't deal with C strings, for example, unlike the other `str*` functions).

Comment: I used strncpy and got a wall of errors, i included the header tho.

Comment: `count == MAXCHAR` - _wow!_  That seems like a bad idea: "If, after copying the terminating null character from `src`, `count` is not reached, additional null characters are written to `dest` until the total of `count` characters have been written." - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy

Comment: OK. I found this which was more helpful as to why. I will edit my reply then.

http://www.victordodon.com/c-functions-you-should-never-use-strncpy/

Comment: The victordodon link doesn't mention that `strncpy` is also unnecessarily wasteful if `n` is big but `src` is short (which is a common case), because `strncpy` always writes exactly `n` chars to `dest` (if `src` is shorter, `'\0'` is written).

Comment: [My own rant about `strncpy`](https://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign `Q = argv[k+1]`. For an array (`Q[MAXCHAR]`), arrayname (`Q`) is the base address. The base address of an array can't be changed.
Assuming `k = 0`, you can use any of the following to get the argv[1] data into Q.

```
memmove(Q, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
```

or

```
snprintf(Q, strlen(argv[1]) + 1, "%s", argv[1]);
```

or

```
strncpy(Q, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
```

or

```
memcpy(Q, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
```

or

```
sprintf(Q, "%s", argv[1]);
```

or

```
strcpy(Q, argv[1]);
```

Here is the program and it's output using memmove:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCHAR 20

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("Not enough arguments");
        return -1;
    }
    char Q[MAXCHAR] = {0};

    memmove(Q, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
    puts(Q);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
me@linux:~$ ./a.out stackexchange
stackexchange
```