# How to assign a char* pointer to a char variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a `struct Track` with variable like this `char artist[81];`

I have a function to create a new track `Track *newTrack(char *artist, char *title, int time);`

But doing this is not possible..

```
track->artist = artist;
```

How can I transform a char array into a char?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to copy C-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings)

Comment: Your destination field is not _a char variable_,  but an array of chars: a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use strcpy ,

```
    strcpy(track->artist, artist);
```

include header

```
      #include<string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use **strcpy**  in this way:

```
strcpy(track->artist, artist);
```

but pay attention:

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the
>   terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

for more details i leave you a useful link : [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)