# I have problem while initializing char array(in constructor) in dynamic zone of memory

Tags: c++

I have problem while initializing char array(in constructor) in dynamic zone of memory.
How can i initialize a dynamic allocated memory type char*

```
class Funkcija
{
protected:
    float k;
    float n;
    char* naziv;

#include "Funkcija.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Funkcija::Funkcija()
{
    k = 1;
    n = 0;
    naziv = new char;
    naziv = 'Name';
    
}
```

Comment: Please use `std::string naziv;`. Then all of these issues go away.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: For one thing you are using the wrong quote characters for a string literal. Use double quote characters `"`

Comment: `naziv = new char;` you allocated space for 1 single character. `naziv = 'Name';` you are using the wrong quotation marks and c-strings don't copy this way.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I am using the one by Siddhartha Rao

Comment: See here to copy a c-string: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings)

Comment: @MarkoIgic And on which page does it teach `new char` and `'Name'`? These are not things we do in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating enough memory for a string `"Name"` (note the *double* quotes).  You are allocating only 1 `char`, and `'Name'` (*single* quotes) is a *multi-byte character* that will not fit in a single `char`.

You need something more like this instead (see the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)):

```cpp
class Funkcija
{
protected:
    float k;
    float n;
    char* naziv;

public:
    Funkcija();
    Funkcija(const Funkcija &);
    ~Funkcija();

    Funkcija& operator=(const Funkcija &);
};
```

```
#include "Funkcija.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

Funkcija::Funkcija()
{
    k = 1;
    n = 0;
    naziv = new char[5];
    std::strcpy(naziv, "Name");
}

Funkcija::Funkcija(const Funkcija &src)
{
    k = src.k;
    n = src.n;
    naziv = new char[std::strlen(src.naziv)+1];
    std::strcpy(naziv, src.naziv);
}

Funkcija::~Funkcija()
{
    delete[] naziv;
}

Funkcija& Funkcija::operator=(const Funkcija &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        Funkcija temp(rhs);
        std::swap(k, temp.k);
        std::swap(n, temp.n);
        std::swap(naziv, temp.naziv);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::string` instead of `char*`, let the compiler handle all of these details for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Funkcija
{
protected:
    float k;
    float n;
    std::string naziv;

public:
    Funkcija();
};
```

```
#include "Funkcija.h"

Funkcija::Funkcija()
{
    k = 1;
    n = 0;
    naziv = "Name";
}
```