# Passing argument from commandline to a malloc array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to duplicate the second commandline argument passed to my program into another string. My goal is to run the program like this:

```
./a.out param1 word param3 param4
```

And get a duplicate of `word`.  How do I do that?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: That's not how you copy a string. You use `strcpy`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to copy C strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I tried using strdup as well as strcpy. Both are giving me segmentation faults with valgrind pointing to that line

Comment: You have `argc` aguments, meaning you should access `argv[argc  - 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is usually name of the executable. So index of the second element you pass in the commandline is 2. Here is how you can do what you're trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    puts("Too few arguments");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char* second_arg = strdup(argv[2]);
  printf("Second argument is %s\n", second_arg);
  free(second_arg);
}
```

If we were duplicating into a fixed string on the stack we would rather do

```
char second_arg[32];
snprintf(second_arg, sizeof(second_arg), "%s", argv[2]);
```

but most of the time we want stretchy strings rather than fixed maximum strings so `strdup` is much preferred.

Comment: Thanks but in the while loop i have mentioned that ' while(argc==2)' this means I'm not accessing the last element right?

Comment: @technextgen if an array has 2 elements, the valid indices are 0 and 1.

Comment: Oh well. If I was a little sure about OP's question I'd consider editing for clarity and then reopening.

Comment: @Joshua I reworded the question. See if it's worth reopening.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Enjoy

Comment: @Joshua I edited your addition slightly since `strncpy` has problems with null-termination.