# C++ compilation error when we pass pointer to struct type argument to function

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

Hello i am new to C++ and came across the below code.

```
typedef char MAC_ID[50]; 

typedef MAC_ID ZEGBEE_MAC_ID;

typedef struct ztest
{
    int x; 
    ZEGBEE_MAC_ID y;
    
}ZTEST;

void zDataPro(int x, ZEGBEE_MAC_ID y)
{
    printf("data %d and string %s", x, y);
    
}
void zExtractData(const ZTEST* pMsg)
{
   // ZEGBEE_MAC_ID pData = pMsg->y; 
    zDataPro(pMsg->x, pMsg->y);
}

int main()
{
    ZTEST data = {2, "12345678"};
    zExtractData(&data);

    return 0;
}
```

At line `zDataPro(pMsg->x, pData);` i am getting below error

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

This error i  think because structure have pointer to const struct type and it's pointer type data member become const and expecting receiving function's (`zDataPro`) second argument also const. But here i can't change the receiver function signature. So changed code like below of function `zExtractData`

```
void zExtractData(const ZTEST* pMsg)
{
   ZEGBEE_MAC_ID pData = pMsg->y; 
   zDataPro(pMsg->x, pData);
}
```

But now i am getting below error

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
    ZEGBEE_MAC_ID pData = pMsg->y;
                                ^
```

So what is correct way to resolve this?

Comment: typedef const char MAC_ID[50];

Comment: @KamilCuk, I agree. The whole piece of code looks more like 'c' anyway

Comment: @PKramer thanks but I can't change that also as it's from 3rd party code, so i need to do something in function "zExtractData"

Comment: If you want to copy C style strings, you need to use something like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings. Better: Write your own type, have it use `std::string` and still do that assignment from the third party structure. `std::string` constructs just fine from C style strings.

Comment: FYI: This is not how a C++ program would have looked. This is C.

Comment: well this is not a c++ code..but if you have to use as it is...then you may wrap it with const_cast and remove const. 
 zDataPro(pMsg->x, const_cast<char*>(pMsg->y));

Comment: `void zDataPro(int x, const char (&y)[50])` for `zDataPro(pMsg->x, pMsg->y);`.

Comment: @hgedek I would only do that as a last resort when I have to make calls to a third party library. And then I would copy the data in non-const buffer first. "const is a contract!"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `const` to `zDataPro` like

```
void zDataPro(const int x, const ZEGBEE_MAC_ID y)
```

because your original parameter in `zExtractData` is `const`, so all the struct's components become `const` for that function, so second function being called from there will also be looking at it as a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy to a local non-const variable first.
Then pass that on, this way you don't have to change any signatures.
You might need to include <string.h>
If you can change zDataPro, then add a const there

```
void zExtractData(const ZTEST* pMsg)
{
    ZTEST local;
    local.x = pMsg->x;
    ::memcpy((void*)(local.y), (void*)(pMsg->y), sizeof(MAC_ID));
    zDataPro(local.x, local.y);
}
```

Comment: The `memcpy` looks odd, I would remove the casts, the `( )` around the variables and definitely the `/ sizeof(char)`, because it would be wrong if it would not be `1`. `memcpy` gets the size, not the number of elements.

Comment: If it looks odd, it's because I haven't done "C" in ages ;) (removed the / it is indeed not needed).