# regexp in C match and return array

Tags: c, regex, match

hi is possible return in C (with library #include <regex.h> ) a  group of  my finded word ?, i find  only example match  and  return number of position , how is possible modify , for return the  exact word in this  position ?
thanks

````
regmatch_t pm;

char *s="mikko mikko";

regoff_t last_match=0;

regcomp(&p, "k", 0);

while(regexec(&p, s+last_match, 1, &pm, 0) == 0) {
printf("start=%d end=%d\n", pm.rm_so + last_match, pm.rm_eo + last_match);
last_match += pm.rm_so+1;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void match_all(regex_t *p, char *sz) {
    regmatch_t whole_match;
    int match = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t length = strlen(sz);
    char result[BUFSIZ];
    int len;

    while (regexec(p, sz + offset, 1, &whole_match, 0) == 0) {
        match = 1;
        len = whole_match.rm_eo - whole_match.rm_so;
        memcpy(result, sz + whole_match.rm_so, len);
        result[len] = 0;
        printf("Match: %s\n", result);

        offset += whole_match.rm_eo + 1; // increase the starting offset
        if (offset > length) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! match) {
        printf("\"%s\" does not contain a match\n", sz);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int r;
    regex_t p;
    r = regcomp(&p, "[[:alnum:]]*k[[:alnum:]]*", 0);
    if (r != 0) {
        printf("regcomp failed\n");
    }
    match_all(&p, "mikko mikko");
    regfree(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kuGsWg). Output:

```
Match: mikko
Match: mikko
```

The `[[:alnum:]]*k[[:alnum:]]*` regex matches zero or more alphanumeric chars, `k` and then again zero or more alphanumeric.

Comment: thanks so much  but is possible  return inside of  array ??

Comment: @RubensBarrichello77 What kind of array do you have in mind? Please provide exact type. See [Proper way to copy C strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings) and [How do I create an array of strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c/1095006) also.

Comment: example  i want analize  a text , and in this  text  can retrun 3  word  or  50  word i dont know  how many  word return and  how many long is  the  word , how  is possible  insert in array all  in  dynamic mode i  suppose

Comment: @RubensBarrichello77 You are not making it any clearer. Please edit the question with a sample array you have in mind. You should always provide exected output in the question.

Comment: sorry , i dont know  what array  return  sure  is  char array ,  but i dont  know   dimention, the  dimention  depend of  how many word  find in text ,

Comment: @RubensBarrichello77 So you want some kind of `char arr[x][y]`?

Comment: sorry i try to explain much better , i want  like final result somthing  like this  Local $aArray = StringRegExp('<test>a</test> <test>b</test> <test>c</Test>', '(?i)<test>(.*?)</test>', 3)   custom function , that match  somthing (i specify example like this  '(?i)<test>(.*?)</test>' ) in global mode (i specify like this 3) for  all text or  phrases i give it , i want  sotred my result or  many result (is variable) in array , i think i must use realloc? and  incrase  the  array ?

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

 typedef struct {
  int *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, int element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}


char result[BUFSIZ];
Array MatchResult;
int CtrlMatcH;


void match_all(regex_t *p, char *sz) {

    regmatch_t whole_match;
    int match = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t length = strlen(sz);
    int len;
    int ctrl=0;
    initArray(&MatchResult, 5);  // initially 5 elements
    // sz=+1;

    // return how many match have 
    while (regexec(p, sz + offset, 1, &whole_match, 0) == 0) {
        match = 1;
        len = whole_match.rm_eo - whole_match.rm_so;
        memcpy(result, sz + whole_match.rm_so, len);
        result[len] = 0;
        printf("Match: %s\n", result);  
        size_t sz += strlen(result) +1
        insertArray(&MatchResult, sz); 
        ++ctrl;
        if (ctrl == 1) {
        strcpy(MatchResult, result);
        }
        strcat(MatchResult, result);

        offset += whole_match.rm_eo + 1; // increase the starting offset
        if (offset > length) {
            break;
        }
    }
        printf("%s\n", MatchResult);

    if (! match) {
        printf("\"%s\" does not contain a match\n", sz);
    }
}

RING_FUNC(ring_stringregexp)
{
    int argc;
    char* argv;
    int r;
    regex_t p;
    r = regcomp(&p, "[[:alnum:]]*k[[:alnum:]]*", 0);
    if (r != 0) {
        printf("regcomp failed\n");
    }
    match_all(&p, "mikko mikko");
    printf("Match2: %s\n", result);
    regfree(&p);
}

RING_API void ringlib_init(RingState *pRingState)
{ 
    ring_vm_funcregister("stringregexp",ring_stringregexp);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).